# IFR plan only with GPS

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, gnss

I'm right before CFII checkride

I understand that if it is without WAAS, I need navigational equipment other than GPS because I can flight plan based on GPS either destination or alternate.
However, If I don't need an alternate for good weather and just plan to use GPS approach at my destination is it allowed I can flight plan with failed VOR?
91.205 (d) navigational equipment for route to be flown means just navigational equipment (not necessarily ground-based one) and If I don't need alternate I think I can flight plan legally on GPS,,, but I'm not sure. I wonder if "either destination or alternate" means if I don't need an alternate, still I have to possess equipment other than GPS ...  english is so difficult for foreign student. would you guys help me?

Answer (score 2):

No, you need an alternate source of navigation to use a non-WAAS GPS at all. From AIM 1-1-17(b)(2)(a)(2):

> Aircraft using un-augmented GPS (TSO-C129() or TSO-C196()) for navigation under IFR must be equipped with an alternate approved and operational means of navigation suitable for navigating the proposed route of flight. (Examples of alternate navigation equipment include VOR or DME/DME/IRU capability). Active monitoring of alternative navigation equipment is not required when RAIM is available for integrity monitoring. Active monitoring of an alternate means of navigation is required when the GPS RAIM capability is lost.

In short, not only must you have backup navigational equipment, you can only fly routes that you could navigate even if your GPS fails.